# jQuery menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get a jQuery menu working which hovers out every single item. Here is the [fiddle code!](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippB/wneTh/). How you will probably see in the result. When I hover one item all are affected. Where is my mistake?

**Here is the javascript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Remove outline from links
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).blur();
    });

    //When mouse rolls over
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'200px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $("li").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({height:'140px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

});
```

If the rest is also necessary please take a look at the [fiddle code.](http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippB/wneTh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about CSS. Bigger 'li' expands your 'ul'. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Remove outline from links
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).blur();
    });

    //When mouse rolls over
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'-60px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $("li").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'0px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VpQkE/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set a negative top margin when you open it up.  Though that could prove problematic with the lis being floated.

```
 //When mouse rolls over
    $("li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'height':'200px','margin-top':'-60px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
    });

//When mouse is removed
$("li").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'height':'140px','margin-top':'0px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});
```